# Anatomically Correct Lamia

Tags: creature-design, mythical-creatures, anatomically-correct

The lamia is a creature that originated in ancient greek mythology, but has been depicted in many forms over time. This question asks about the most recent interpretation as a sphinx-like hooved quadruped. More specifically, it has:

- Hindlegs like a goat
- Paws on its forelegs
- Human-like head and breasts
- External testicles
- Scaly skin

Other traits it may have include:

- Having testicles and breasts in the same individual
- No penis
- Foul smell
- Never sleeps
- Feeds on human children

What evolutionary pressures could create a creature like this?

Comment: The word *lamia* is feminine. Moreover, perhaps surprisingly, words have meanings; and it is rather late in the day to change the meaning of Greek and Latin words. Latin [lamias](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dlamia1) (it's a common noun in Latin) are by definition evil witches; they do not have testicles, internal or external. (Or they may be flatfishes or owls.) *Greek*  [Lamia](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3D*la%2Fmia^) (proper noun) is a monster. (Or a shark.)

Comment: This question askes about the lamia in History of Four-footed Beasts. Even if the Lamia is a specific creature, it realistically must be part of a species, and that species needs to be refered to by some name

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The lamia may have evolved from an early marsupial. In order to protect themselves, they may have adapted to spray foul smelling substances from the glands near the tail like a skunk. They may also grow scales over their body, to protect themselves from predator's attacks. In order to avoid being attacked in their sleep, they may evolve to sleep less, until they no longer sleep at all. They may also evolve to mate faster. This would require the penis to shorten, as a longer penis takes longer to extend and insert. This trend may continue until they have no penis, and mate by something like a cloacal kiss. They may later evolve to become cursorial predators. This would require them to adapt to move faster, such as extending the limbs, and losing lateral toes, reducing the hind-feet into hooves and the fore-feet into paws (as there would still need to be multiple toes to allow them to climb to the pouch after birth). They would also have to evolve stronger jaws that are better adapted for eating meat. Eventually, they may come into contact with humans. They may evolve to appear more human, to lure away children for food. This would require the head to shorten, the scales on the head to be replaced by hair and bare skin on the face, alongside other changes. They may also gain other human features, such as bare fatty 'breasts'. These changes would create a lamia

Comment: Strange how it evolved from a marsupial, given that there are no marsupials in Greece or Italy... (Or, for that matter, in the Old World in general.)

Comment: There are marsupials in  the americas, which were known in the western world for over a century before the creation of History of Four-footed Beasts